# Errors in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm new to webdevelopment, and have made my first MVC application.
Everything works and looks fine om my development machine, but when I publish it to the server I get some errors in Internet Explorer.
But Everything looks and works ok in other browsers, for example Google Chrome.

Does anyone have any idea about what I have done wrong so I know what to look for?
If you need to see any code, please let me know what parts as I don't know what I have done wrong.

[Error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vq0jM.png)

//Edit
Here is the references that I have in the head tag in _Layout.cshtml

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
```

And my BundleConfig.cs looks like this

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bootbox.min.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/Site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/themes/base/accordion.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/base/all.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/base/autocomplete.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/base/base.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/base/button.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/base/core.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/base/dialog.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/base/draggable.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/base/menu.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/base/progressbar.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/base/resizable.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/base/selectable.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/base/selectmenu.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/base/slider.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/base/sortable.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/base/spinner.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/base/tabs.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/base/theme.css",
                      "~/Content/themes/base/tooltip.css"));

    }
```

Comment: How are you referencing your javascript files? jquery couldn't be loaded. Use [page inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor) to see if you get errors

Comment: Please add error messages to the question. Links might get obsolated.

Comment: it seems you are also new to StackOverflow, please go through  (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @RaraityL - I have updated my post with some code.

Comment: u sure it works on other browsers? try do a refresh and see if the scripts are just from the cache

Comment: Yes, I have cleared all cache in all browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out what was causing this issue.

In Internet Explorer settings, "Display intranet sites in Compability View" was selected.
Unchecked it and now everything works.